# Programmatically add an ImageView to Layout

Tags: java, android, imageview, dynamic-ui

I'm trying to add a bunch of ImageView on my UI using a loop, the problem is that I have no Idea if the ImageView is being added or not because when I run the app it just gives me a blank white screen.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Log.d("test", "ok"); //the loop works btw
                poster.setId(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ImageView poster = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                poster.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myPoster);


                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams posterParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                posterParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                posterParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                posterParams.width = 160; //is this DP?
                posterParams.height = 220;
                relativeLayout.addView(poster, posterParams);

            }
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

**EDIT**

I added another piece of code just to test if a widget will be added without using a loop:

```
  //test
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
  Button btn = new Button(this);
  btn.setText("this is a button");
  btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  layout.addView(btn);
```

And I still get the same result, just blank.

Comment: see my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you are giving exactly the same parameter to each `ImageView` this causes all your `ImageView` lays on Like `STACK` only the last one will be visible to you. You may use `ScrollView` to see if the `ImageView`s actually added to your root layout
- Secondly, set layout parameters to your dynamic `ImageView`s not your root layout.

**Update**

How to use `ScrollView`,

First of all, your XML should contain `ScollView` and a child (`LinearLayout` in our case but you can choose any layout depending on your use case) for placing your `ImageView`

```
    <ScrollView>
      <LinearLayout
       android:id = "imageViewPlaceHolder">

      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Secondly, in your Java code, you should find an inner layout to add views as follows

```
LinearLayout placeHolder = findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlaceHolder);
```

Then you are ready to add `ImageViews` into `placeHolder` since your `placeHolder` wrapped with `ScrollView` it will create a scroll dynamically if the content height goes beyond the dedicated height.

```
placeHolder.addView(yourImageView);
```

Adding everything from Java

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
hsv.setLayoutParams(yourLayoutParams);

LinearLayout myPlaceHolder = new LinearLayout(context);
myPlaceHolder.setLayoutParams(yourLayoutParamsForLinearLayout);

myPlaceHolder.addView(yourDesiredImageView);

hsv.addView(myPlaceHolder);

yourRootLayout.addView(hsv);
```

Hope it makes sense, feel free to ask any clarification

Comment: What do you mean by "use ScrollView", can you give me an example code? thanks

Comment: Thanks, what I did is created the LinearLayout using xml then create an instance of it in java //findViewbyID() then addView(). I'm still wondering though how can I make this work without creating the LinearLayout using xml but using java instead.

Comment: how to get the root layout?

Comment: Most probably `relativeLayout` is your root layout

Comment: I removed the relative layout now, I'm only using the linear layout. So it would be basically the same scrollview > linearlayout > imageview. Which does not work for me

Comment: That all I can do for you, for now, I suggest starting bounty to the question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_info);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, text);

listView.addHeaderView(creatHeader(getString(R.string.abuot_email),getResources().getString(R.string.email_info)));
listView.addHeaderView(creatHeader(getString(R.string.about_phone),getResources().getString(R.string.admin_phone_num)));
listView.addHeaderView(creatHeader(getString(R.string.about_copyright), getResources().getString(R.string.copyright_info)));
listView.addHeaderView(creatHeader(getString(R.string.about_version),getResources().getString(R.string.version_info)));

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Method creatHeader:

```
public View creatHeader(String title, String text) {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lv_item_header_info, null);
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)).setText(title);
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText)).setText(text);
    return v;
}
```

Layout file for items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sssssssss"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```